# How to Test Xamarin ViewModel with xUnit in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xunit

I want to test a Xamarin view model with xUnit. When the code is build using command line on Mac, the following error are show:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(283,5): error NETSDK1073: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF' was not recognized

If `<GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>false</GenerateErrorForMissingTargetingPacks>` is used on .csproj, the project compiles, but the following error are reported when I try to run the test.

> System.BadImageFormatException : Duplicate type with name 'App.<>PropertyChangedEventArgs'

The view model are show below (part of the class). Fody and PropertyChanged.Fody are used to automate the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.

```cs
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class ListaTarefasViewModel : ViewModelBase, IHandleViewAppearing, IHandleViewDisappearing
{

    public ListaTarefasViewModel(
        ITarefaService tarefaService,
        ITarefaRepository tarefaRepository,
        ITarefaRetornoItensRepository tarefaRetornoItensRepository,
        INotificationService notificationService,
        IUsuarioRepository usuarioRepository,
        IProdutoRepository produtoRepository)
    {
        this.tarefaService = tarefaService;
        this.tarefaRepository = tarefaRepository;
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
        this.usuarioRepository = usuarioRepository;
        this.tarefaRetornoItensRepository = tarefaRetornoItensRepository;
        this.produtoRepository = produtoRepository;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The test class:

```cs
public class ListaTarefasViewModelTest : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Mock<ListaTarefasViewModel> listaTarefasViewModelMock;

    public ListaTarefasViewModelTest()
    {
        listaTarefasViewModelMock = new Mock<ListaTarefasViewModel>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ShouldConfigureTipoTarefaWhenInitializeAsync()
    {
        object tipoTarefa = TipoTarefaEnum.Inventario;
        await listaTarefasViewModelMock.Object.InitializeAsync(tipoTarefa);
        Assert.Equal(TipoTarefaEnum.Inventario, listaTarefasViewModelMock.Object.TipoTarefa);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rony! I just finished adding Unit Tests to my GitTrends app and wanted to share them as an example of how to write Unit Tests for ViewModels for a Xamarin.Forms app: https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends/tree/master/GitTrends.UnitTests/Tests/ViewModels

Answer (score 4):

### Build and Execution Errors

The error

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.300/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(283,5): error NETSDK1073: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF' was not recognized

was caused by the use of the package [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup), because it depends of WPF through Xamarin.Forms ([Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf)). This can be resolved by using `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` on the `.csproj` file.

Example:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Rg.Plugins.Popup" Version="2.0.0.3">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Reference about the `.csproj` file configuration: [Package references (PackageReference) in project files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets)

The error

> System.BadImageFormatException : Duplicate type with name 'App.<>PropertyChangedEventArgs'

was solved by cleaning the entire solution or the shared project, but this is needed to be made before any test. This appears to be caused by [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) or [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged).

That are issues related to the this error, but none was resolved by now: [issue on PropertyChanged.Fody repository](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/issues/25) and [issue on  MarcStan /
resource-embedder repository](https://github.com/MarcStan/resource-embedder/issues/13).

### Unit Test

Finally, the code uses [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) and the test was made with [xUnit](https://xunit.net/).
The class was tested with the mock getting all the dependencies from another mocks.

```cs
var tarefaService = Mock.Of<ITarefaService>();
var tarefaRepository = Mock.Of<ITarefaRepository>();
// ...
var mockListaTarefasViewModel = new Mock<ListaTarefasViewModel>(
    MockBehavior.Loose,
    tarefaService,
    tarefaRepository,
    // ..
);
mockListaTarefasViewModel
    .Setup(/* .. */)
    .Verifiable();
mockListaTarefasViewModel.Verify();
```

Comment: Thnx. This happened to me today with "Xamarin.CommunityToolkit" Version="1.1.0-pre2"